# apply naive algorithm on cvs file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-matching

i have big cvs file with 1740 rows and i want to compare line by line in file with entire same file.
the problem is i cant figure out how i can send lines to the algorithm and specify to not compare with same line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i7Tb.png)

```
import csv


with open("pcr_data.csv", "r") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
  `  data = []
     for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(row)
        # print(data)

# Python program to read CSV file line by line


    # Iterate over each row in the csv 
    # file using reader object
    
def naive_string_matching(text, pattern):
    n = len(text)
    m = len(pattern)
    for i in range(n - m + 1):
        j = 0
        while j < m and text[i + j] == pattern[j]:
            j += 1
        if j == m:
            return i
    return -1

def search_in_file(file_path, pattern):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        text = file.readline();
        index = naive_string_matching(text, pattern)
        if index != -1:
            print("The pattern found at index: ", index)
        else:
            print("The pattern was not found in the file")


for r in range len(data):
    file_path = data
    pattern =r
    search_in_file(file_path, pattern)
```

help me please.

Comment: To be clear, you want to *compare* every line to all other lines in the file?

Comment: exactly and  my data such like  [0,0,1,0,1,0]

Answer (score 0):

> send lines to the algorithm and specify to not compare with same line.

Create all combinations, taken two at a time using itertools.combinations. This will prevent comparing a line to itself.

```
from itertools import combinations

for line_one,line_two in combinations(data,r=2):
    # assert line_one != line_two
    # send line_one and line_two to the algorithm
```

---

```
data = list('abcd')
for one,two in combinations(data,r=2):
    assert one != two
    print((one,two),end=' | ')
>>>
('a', 'b') | ('a', 'c') | ('a', 'd') | ('b', 'c') | ('b', 'd') | ('c', 'd') |
```

Comment: i dont think this method could be  successful with my data becuse ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1'] all 1740 row look like this. and i want for example compare this line with complete file

Comment: See the edit without using indices.